# Creating a big Object that has two methods, one of which creates a particular instance of the big Object

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning javascript and I was trying to make the following: create a "complexNum" which represents the structure of complex numbers. I want that object to have two methods, the first one is called "newComplex" which is a function that needs two inputs: real part and imaginary parts, and returns a new object which is a complex number with the specified real and imaginary parts) and one method: the norm, which calculates the norm.

The second method is "sum" and needs two inputs: two complex numbers (as defined by newComplex), and returns another object, a complex number, which is the sum of the two previous complex numbers.

This is my solution:

```
var complexNum= {
    newComplex: function(real,img){
         var z ={
            partreal: real,
            partimg: img,
            norm: function(){
                  var norm= Math.sqrt(this.partimg*this.partimg + this.partreal*this.partreal );
                  return norm;
                   }
            }
         return z;
    },      
    sum: function(a,b){
            var real = a.partreal + b.partreal;
            var img = a.partimg + b.partimg;
            var sum = complexNum.newComplex(real,img);
            return sum;
            }
    }
```

Is this the better solution? One of my questions in particular is if the object newComplex is actually a sub-object of the complexNum object (which is my objective) or if it's a completely new object with no relationship with complexNum.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you seem to be just dealing with plain Objects, what is returned by `newComplex` is a plain Object - there is nothing `sub` about it

Comment: Thinking about it, isn't it the most natural thing? I don't want a complex number like "1+i" to have the sum method or the "create new complex number" method. It should only have the real and imaginary properties and the norm method. Is that correct?

Comment: I thought your question was about object types or some such, you're just dealing with plain objects, so "sub-object" makes no contextual sense

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, objects are needlesly complex IMO. How would you approach creatomg a "complex numbers" object with those methods?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, I don't understand what you're asking :p

Comment: I am asking why, for example, "instanceof" doesn't work.

 var Z = complexNum.newComplex(1,1);
 alert("is Z a complex number?"+Z instanceof complexNum);

Comment: because nowhere are you using the `new` operator, so you're not dealing with that type of object

Comment: well that's exactly what I want, I want Z to be that type of object, how can I do it? :S

Comment: function newComplex(real,img){
  this.partreal = real;
  this.partimg = img;
  this.norm = function(){
    //bla bla bla
  }
 var complexNum = {
  new: function(real,img){
    var z= new nuevocomplejo(real,img);
    return z;
    },  
  sum: function(a,b){
       var real = a.partreal + b.partreal;
    var img = a.partimg + b.partimg;
    var sum = complejos.nuevo(real,img);
    return sum;
       }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it how you want, so that a complex number is an instance of complexNum.Complex for example:

```js
var complexNum = (function() {
    var Complex = function Complex(real, img) {
        this.partreal = real;
        this.partimg = img;
    };
    Complex.prototype.norm = function() {
        return Math.sqrt(this.partimg * this.partimg + this.partreal * this.partreal);
    }
    return {
        Complex: Complex,
        newComplex: function(real, img) {
            return new Complex(real, img);
        },
        sum: function(a, b) {
            var real = a.partreal + b.partreal;
            var img = a.partimg + b.partimg;
            return complexNum.newComplex(real, img);
        }
    }
})();
var a = complexNum.newComplex(1, 1);
var b = complexNum.newComplex(2, 2);
console.log(a instanceof complexNum.Complex);
console.log(complexNum.sum(a, b) instanceof complexNum.Complex);
```